# Pass IStorageContext as parameter of a Cmdlet - Unable to find type [IStorageContext]

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-storage, azure-powershell, powershell-cmdlet

I'm going to create a Cmdlet which accepts `IStorageContext` as parameter. But when running the cmdlet, it throws a `TypeNotFound` exception stating:

> Unable to find type [IStorageContext]

Here is the Cmdlet:

```
Function SomeCmdlet {
  param(
    [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [IStorageContext]$storageContext
  )
  New-AzureStorageContainer -Name "ContainerName" -Context $storageContext -Permission Off
}
```

In fact, I've created a Storage Account using [`New-AzureRmStorageAccount`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.storage/new-azurermstorageaccount?view=azurermps-4.4.0) and I want to pass value of its `Context` property to my method and in my method, using [`New-AzureStorageContainer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azure.storage/new-azurestoragecontainer?view=azurermps-4.4.0) i want to create a container. Here is the documentation for `Context` parameter:

```
-Context
Specifies a context for the new container.

Type:                       IStorageContext
Position:                   Named
Default value:              None
Accept pipeline input:      True (ByPropertyName, ByValue)
Accept wildcard characters: False
```

I found-out that the full name of [`IStorageContext`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/blob/77afe7be817242e61026069d2e8d3befe7984427/src/Common/Commands.Common.Authentication.Abstractions/Interfaces/IStorageContext.cs) is:

- `Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.Abstractions.IStorageContext`

But even with using above type name as parameter type I received the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `[IStorageContext]` you can use either of following types:

- `[Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Common.Storage.AzureStorageContext]`
- `[object]`

So the method would be:

```
Function SomeCmdlet {
  param(
    [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [object]$storageContext
  )
  New-AzureStorageContainer -Name "ContainerName" -Context $storageContext -Permission Off
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Import-Module Azure.Storage` should load all related types together with the module into the current Powershell session.

In a specific script, you should use `#Requires -Modules Azure.Storage` to get the module loaded without explicit `Import-Module` call.

In case you need a specific type from a specific library, use `Add-Type` cmdlet. Provided that you have the Azure SDK installed in the default location, load the type with following:

```
Add-Type -LiteralPath "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\PowerShell\Storage\Azure.Storage\Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.Abstractions.dll"
```

Comment: Thank Alex. The code which I shared can be simply used to reproduce the problem. Did you test your proposed solutions?

Comment: Which version of `Azure.Storage` module are you using?