# Powershell Azure Function on Linux can't find types

Tags: linux, azure, powershell, azure-functions

running linux powershell azure function with classes and it will not find types.

here's an example func script from the template with me adding a couple fields on a class

these fields show up as unknown types on my local dev environment and in the portal on azure

```
# POST method: $req
using namespace Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Profile.Models.Core
using namespace Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.Abstractions

class Test{
    hidden [PSAzureContext] $azureContext
    hidden [IStorageContext] $storageContext

    Test([PSAzureContext] $ctx, [IStorageContext] $storectx){
        $this.azureContext = $ctx
        $this.storageContext = $storectx
    }
}

$requestBody = Get-Content $req -Raw | ConvertFrom-Json
$name = $requestBody.name

# GET method: each querystring parameter is its own variable
if ($req_query_name) 
{
    $name = $req_query_name 
}

Out-File -Encoding Ascii -FilePath $res -inputObject "Hello $name"
```

Comment: If those namespaces come from a PowerShell module, try `Import-Module` at the top of your code so it loads the needed assemblies

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon the namespaces are coming from Az module

Comment: Try to import the module at the top of the code, if that didnt help then the answer is in this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42837447/powershell-unable-to-find-type-when-using-ps-5-classes and we can close this as duplicate

Comment: You need a "using assembly".  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_using?view=powershell-7.3

Comment: @jdweng do you know which assembly and where? especially on the Azure box that this is going to run?

Comment: It would be the same as your namespace.

Comment: @jdweng I'm sorry but that doesn't make sense, these are Azure cmdlet dlls

Comment: I just removed the type info from the code for these variable/methods

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of below code in your Powershell run file, For IStorageContext to work, You can refer this [**answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46466782/pass-istoragecontext-as-parameter-of-a-cmdlet-unable-to-find-type-istoragecon) by Reza Aghaei

**My run.ps in Azure Function Http Trigger Powershell:-**

```
using namespace System.Net

# Input bindings are passed in via param block.
param($Request, $TriggerMetadata)

Import-Module Az.Resources
Import-Module Az.Accounts



$AppId="xxxxxb838-6d26a31435cb"
$AppSecret="xxxxxZ3ZgxRt8313-CS0ifbLE"

$SecureSecret = $AppSecret | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force

$Credential = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential `
-ArgumentList $AppId,$SecureSecret

$TenantID="xxxx4ce4-99ed-af9038592395"

Connect-AzAccount -ServicePrincipal -Credential $Credential -Tenant $TenantID 

$AccountName = "siliconrgaaa6"
$ResourceGroupName="siliconrg"

$StorageAccount=Get-AzStorageAccount -Name $AccountName  -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName
# $storageAccountBlob=Get-AzStorageBlob -Container "blob" -Context $storageContext  -Prefix "host"

Function SomeCmdlet {
  param(
    [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [object]$storageContext
  )
  New-AzureStorageContainer -Name "blob" -Context $storageContext -Permission Off
}

$StorageAccount
$ResponseMessage="The kind of storage account is " + $StorageAccount.kind

Push-OutputBinding -Name response -Value ([HttpResponseContext]@{
    StatusCode = [System.Net.HttpStatusCode]::OK
    Body = $ResponseMessage })
```

Make sure you uncomment Az module in requirements.psd like below:-

[image]

**Output:-**

[image]

[image]

**Http Triggered successfully:-**

[image]

Comment: try this by making a class, you will quickly find out you can't use types in a powershell class